# Laravel 5+ Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица `users` и `tickets` связаны они по полям `users.id = tickets.create_by`. Для выборки пользователя из конкретного тикета я написал код:

```
class Ticket extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tickets';

    public function user(){
           return  $this->hasOne('App\User','id','create_by');
        }
}
```

**use**: `Ticket::find(1)->user`

Как реализовать выборку так чтобы при написании `Ticket::all()->withUsers()` я мог получить список всех тикетов с пользователями.

**Дополнение к вопросу**: 
На данный момент в таблице есть много связующих полей (*внешних ключей*), как реализовать через модели выборку таким образом чтобы вместе с записями (*тикетами*) подтягивались данные по ключам. Можно конечно просто реализовать запросом но будет ли это правильно да и не очень хочется т.к уверен что можно лучше.

p.s буду рад нескольким вариантам решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) – когда вы хотите сразу получить данные из связанных таблиц:

```
$ticketId = 123;
$ticket = Tickets::with('user')->find( $ticketId);
$user = $ticket->user;
```

---

В `with()` можно перечислить несколько отношений:

```
$ticket = Ticket::with('user','event','promocode')->find( $id);
```

Для многоуровневых отношений используется точка-как-разделитель:

```
$ticket = Ticket::with('user','event.city')->find( $id);
```

---

P.S. лучше класс называть в единственном числе – ведь он представляет собой один билет: не `Tickets`, а `Ticket`. Вот класс `User` у вас хорошо именован : )

Comment: А есть вариант использования конструкции `Tickets::all()->with('user')`?

Comment: @Shadow33 такого варианта нет. Дело в том, что `with()` [возвращает](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) объект Query Builder – так же, как, например, и всякие `where()` – очень грубо говоря, это всё конструирует SQL запрос. А `all()` уже возвращает сами записи, так же, как и `get()` или `first()` – на выходе массив с объектами результатов.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос если в таблице много полей связующих то есть индекс из другой таблицы. Как поступить в поделе чтобы при запросе к  функции вернуть все записи со всеми данными. Не хочется писать просто запросом хотя можно.

Comment: @Shadow33, вы пробовали читать документацию [по ссылке](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) в ответе, или хотя бы код примеров в ней? Там же есть: `$books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();` для множественных отношений и `$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();` для многоуровневых.